# Mono 3.0.0: Could not load file or assembly: System.Web.Extensions.dll, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: apache, mono, servicestack, mod-mono

I am hosting a ServiceStack web service in Apache with mod-mono, I have mono-3.0.0, and xsp-2.10.2.
I hosted the hello world example targeting .Net framework 2.0 and using mod-mono-server2, and it worked fine.
I then change the project to target .Net framework 4.0 and using mod-mono-server4.
I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. **The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'**
>     at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string)
>     at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.LoadAssembly (System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo info, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 al) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartMethods () [0x00000] in :0

But the file System.Web.Extensions is installed in the GAC:

> ## gacutil -l System.Web.Extensions
>
> The following assemblies are installed into the GAC:
>   System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   **System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35**
>   Number of items = 3

Even if I set MonoPath to specifically get the 4.0 version the same error occurs:

> MonoPath /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0

I also noticed this:

> Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.5 (tarball Fri Oct 28 10:20:24 IST 2011); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1

Mono Runtime version says 2.10.5 although I have mono-3.0.0 installed, I don't know if this information has value for this issue.

I tried running mod-mono-server4 directly and I got this error message:

> ## mod-mono-server4
>
> mod-mono-server4
>   Missing method System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler::Create(object,object,XmlNode) in assembly /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/System.Configuration.dll
>   Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create'.
>     at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in :0
>     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in :0
>     at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in :0
>     at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in :0
>     at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
>   mod-mono-server4
>   Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server
>   Root directory: /usr/local/bin
>   Error: There's already a server listening on /tmp/mod_mono_server

I googled for this error and it lead me to this bug:

> https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7967

Maybe the error on mod-mono-server4 is the origin of the other bug... I will try to get xsp 3.0 and see if it solves the problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How did you install Mono 3.0? For me, it looks like you've compiled from sources but configured with the wrong prefix.

Comment: I followed this instructions: http://wiki.phonicuk.com/Installing-Mono-in-CentOS-5-x.ashx I just changed "mono-2.10.8.tar.gz" for "mono-3.0.0.tar.bz2"

Comment: You should potentially care about the `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` part. Execute the `whereis mono` command and see what's the first prefix. `/usr` maybe? In that case do the procedure again with the prefix you've obtained. After that run `mono --version` to be sure.

Comment: I found out that the httpd.conf line that had MonoServerPath default "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4" was being totally ignored, because I renamed the file and Apache kept getting mod-mono-server2. I was missing "MonoAutoApplication disabled". After adding that line it started getting the "mod-mono-server4.exe" but with the error it had when I ran it directly, so I pointed mod-mono-server4 to /usr/local/src/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/mod-mono-server4.exe and the error disappeared.

Comment: Now I have another problem, when I call the service nothing happens, the browser waits forever and Apache error log is empty. If I remove "MonoPath /usr/local/lib/mono/4.0" I get a System.TypeLoadException when the AppHost initializes, but at least I get something. How can I know what is happening in the first case? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This error is caused because of an issue in the System.Configuration assembly for Mono's implementation of the **.NET 4.0 framework** when used by Mod_Mono / XSP. It's trying to read in the "**MonoServerDefaultIndexFiles**" appSetting key but can't find the Create factory method.

It took a a day or two to figure out that the solution is to edit the following file...

> /opt/mono/bin/mod-mono-server4

...by changing the default value of **4.0** to ***4.5*** in this line:

> exec /opt/mono/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS
>   "/opt/mono/lib/mono/**4.5**/mod-mono-server4.exe" "$@"

With this resolved, the next issue i faced was with the fact that Mono replaces the built in AspNetMembershipProvider with a SqliteMembershipProvider through its Settings Map feature. I added the following line in my Web.config's appSettings section to disable this default behavior:

> "<add key="MonoAspnetInhibitSettingsMap" value="disabled"/>"

After a couples days of chasing, my MVC3 app was successfully running on Mono 3.0.3 (latest at the time of this writing) / XSP 2.10 / Mod_Mono 2.10

Comment: More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961694/mono-2-11-with-nginx-or-apache